# Windows cmd - findstr and gawk or how would you pull the below data out

Tags: parsing, cmd, gawk, findstr

I was wondering if it's possible to use findstr and/or gawk to return the output of a windows cmd exactly how I need it to be. I'm currently returning the output raw, then stripping out the blank lines, and parsing out what I need. Just as a learning thing, I was hoping I could see how this can be done better.

The raw output:

```
Change 2086888 on 2012/01/23 by user1@server1

        test_description_1.2.3.4@29816

Change 2086888 on 2012/01/23 by user1@server2

        test_description2_4.5.6.7@29816

Change 2078677 on 2012/01/20 by user2@server1

        test_description3_7.8.9.10@29816
```

I take that output and parse it out to this with php:

```
1. 2086888,test_description_1.2.3.4@29816
2. 2086888,test_description2_4.5.6.7@29816
3. 2078677,test_description3_7.8.9.10@29816
```

To make it a little easier on myself, I remove the blank lines from the output by piping it to findstr and using /V "^$". So it's  | findstr /V "^$".

How can I get the output that I parse out with php directly from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` command in cmd.exe skips blank lines, so it may be easier to parse it this way:

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set linenum=1
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (output.txt) do @(
  if %%A==Change set result=%%B
  if not %%A==Change (
    echo !linenum!. !result!,%%A
    set /a linenum=!linenum!+1
  )
)   
endlocal
```

Comment: this is pretty good and works. i was hoping there would be a way to do it without for, but i think it's the only way. thanks